# Components of graph with edges given by congruence condition

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G_n = (V_n, E_n)$ denote the graph with vertex set $V_n = \{0, 1, 2, \dotsc, n – 1\}$ and edge set $E_n = \left\{\{i, j\}: i + j \equiv 1 \pmod{n}\right\}$ where $n \ge 3$. How many components does $G_n$ have for $n \ge 3$?

The answer is $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ if we allow loops. I've gotten the answer by making graphs for different values of $n$. Can anyone help with a constructive proof?

Comment: If you've been constructing the graphs by hand, you should see a pattern. What's the pattern you see?

Comment: Sir +Mike, Thanks for you comment. What I see is - this question is reduced to the combinatorial problem of finding number of combination (x,y) = n+1.

Comment: Basically, yeah, ... and what's the pattern you see when drawing the graphs? What led you to conclude that the answer should be $\lceil n/2 \rceil$?

Comment: Sir +Mike, I've just tried with n=3,4,5 & got the answer. But the pattern I see somewhat is like (n/2,n/2+1), (n/2-1,n/2+2),(n/2-2,n/2+3) ... Am I correct? Apart from trivial (0,1) edge.

Comment: Thanks Sir +Mike for helping me, I got it counting terms of this series alone. :)

Comment: Yeah, they pair up. Can you make an argument why no other edges can join each pair? Why the best we can do is pairs?

Comment: Because sum of vertices paired by the edge must be exactly n+1.

Comment: Why can't we get two vertices that sum to $1$ or $2n+1$ or $3n+1$? (and don't you need a separate case for the vertices named $0$ and $1$?)

Comment: Sir + Mike, here is my complete solution. http://gateoverflow.in/87560/let-gn-un-en-denote-the-graph-with-vertex-vn-0-1-2-n-1?show=87619#a87619

Comment: Your solution? If you have a solution, why would you ask the question here? Why not type out the solution yourself here?

Comment: No, I got the solution after posting here when you started giving me clue. :)

Comment: Then you should type up your solution here to help other people who find this question later.

Comment: Sure sir, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.

Since sum would be $n+1$. Patterns of edges would be like this:

$(\lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor, \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor +1), (\lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor-1, \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor +2),...,(2,\lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor+\lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor
-1)$

Therefore total pairs $= \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor -1 -1+1 = \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor -1$

Considering trivial $(0,1)$ Total pairs or edges are $= \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor$.

Now, with $n$ vertices & $k$ components a forest has $n-k$ edges.

$\implies n - k = \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor$

$\implies k = n - \lfloor{(n/2)}\rfloor = 
\lceil{(n/2)}\rceil$

Comment: You should check out [this guide on how to nicely typeset mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment:  Will try sir.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are working $\bmod n$, I think it would be easier to name the vertices $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$ instead; the problem is the same. We see pretty quickly by playing around that the edges

$$(1,n)\quad(2,n\!-\!1)\quad\dotsb\quad\left(\lfloor n/2\rfloor,  1+\lfloor n/2\rfloor\right)$$

must be in our graph. So there are at most $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ connected components, each component having one edge except for a single component with an isolated vertex if $n$ is odd. This is also all the components. On the contrary if we suppose that our graph has some edges $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ for distinct vertices $a$ and $c$, we would have

$$a+b \equiv 1  \quad\text{and}\quad b+c \equiv 1\;.$$

Subtracting these two congruence we get that $a\equiv c \pmod n$. But since our vertices are just $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ this is only possible if $a=c$.